# Rails Hotwire - How to search within existing form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

I have form that has a section that displays a series of checkboxes for what groups a user manages. I want to add a search box at the top of the checkboxes that allows them to search a name and have it filter the results. From there they can check whatever ones they need to and submit the main form.

The only way I have ever done this is by triggering a from submission. It is not working (not doing anything) I assume because it is within another form. Is there a way to get this to work like I have it below, or is there a better way to set up this filter?

cardrequest form:

```
<%= form_with(model: cardrequest, id: dom_id(cardrequest), class: "contents") do |form| %>

form fields for cardrequest ...

<div class="mb-4 space-y-4">
    <%= form_with url: search_cardrequests_path, method: :get, data: { controller: "search-form", search_form_target: "form", turbo_frame: "cgs" } do |c| %>
        <div>
            <label for="add-guests">Select Cardholder Groups</label>
            <div class="relative">

            <%= c.search_field :search,  data: { action: "input->search-form#search" }, value: params[:search] %>

        </div>
    <% end %>    
</div>


<div data-controller="checkbox-select-all">
<label>     
    <input type="checkbox"  data-checkbox-select-all-target="checkboxAll" />
    <span class="btn_primary_small">Select All / Deselect All</span>
</label>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "cgs" do %>
    <div class="space-y-3">
        <%= form.collection_check_boxes :cardholdergroup_ids, current_user.cardholdergroups, :id, :friendlyname do |g| %>
        <div class="flex items-center mr-4">
            <%= g.check_box data: { checkbox_select_all_target: 'checkbox' } %>
            <%= g.label %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Stimulus controller:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
static targets = [ "form" ]

search() {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {

    this.formTarget.requestSubmit()
  
  }, 200)
  
  
 }
}
```

cardrequests controller search method:

```
def search
    cardholdergroups = current_user.cardholdergroups
    @cardholdergroups = cardholdergroups.where("friendlyname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") if params[:search].present?   
    render(partial: 'cgs', locals: { cardholdergroups: @cardholdergroups })
end
```

routes:

```
resources :cardrequests do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you have figured this one out yourself. Nested forms are not valid HTML and will result in non-standard behavior. There are many potential solutions - for example you could have two forms (that are not nested) and submitting one updates the other or you can just attach an event handler directly to the select element.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I kind of know what the issue is, just not that great with stimulus enough to know what I should be doing on an input change. Every example I have seen of hotwire filtering involves submitting a form. If you know of any examples of a non form submit hotwire filter let me know!

Comment: The example on https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/ shows attaching an event handler to a button. Switch out the button for a select and `data-action="click->hello#greet"` for `data-action="hello#greet"` (change is the default action for a select).

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at this. Just as I wrote my last reply I stumbled on to this stimulus solution which was exactly what I was looking to do and go tit working: https://onrails.blog/2018/03/15/stimulus-js-tutorial-how-do-i-filter-data-in-a-list-or-table/